# Migrate from OpenFire to Ejabberd

Tags: migration, ejabberd, openfire, sysadmin

Can I migrate from OpenFire to Ejabberd with full data(contacts, messages, etc)?
I found only one solution for migration: export from OpenFire only contacts.

Answer (score 0):

ejabberd itself supports importing from jabberd14, Prosody, and PIEFXIS (XEP-0227) formats. Maybe Openfire supports exporting to one of those formats.

Searching over internet, found this old script
https://github.com/debalance/openfire2ejabberd

Comment: Thank you.
I will check it and give feedback.